# Proof that the kernel of an endomorphism to the power $n$ is a subset of the kernel of the endomorphism to the power $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am expected to know how to prove the following but I can't seem to draw it out.

> Knowing that V is a Vector Space$$
> T:V\to V
> $$
>   Prove the following 
>   $$
> Ker(T^n)\subseteq Ker(T^{n+1})
> $$

How do you go about making the proof? I haven't tried much honestly, but I don't know where to start either. I also have to try and prove the same for the Image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x\in \ker(T^n)$ i.e. $T^n x=0$ so we have

$$T^{n+1}(x)=T(T^n(x))=T(0)=0\implies x\in \ker(T^{n+1})$$

Comment: Makes sense, remind me on the basics here, a linear transformation of 0 will always give 0... or not?

Comment: Yes it's always $0$:
$$T(0)=T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)\implies T(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Start by choosing an arbitrary element of $Ker(T^n)$, and showing it is also in $Ker(T^{n+1})$.

That is, if $v \in Ker(T^n)$, then $T^nv = 0$. What can you say about $T^{n+1}v = T(T^nv)$?